# Antd table header disapppear when using scroll Y and dynamic columns

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm having issue when rendering dynamic columns for Antd table, when I re-render the columns, the table's header just disappear.

`getDefaultColumns()`

```
const getDefaultColumns = () => {
    return [
      {
        title: <span className={`table-header`}>STT</span>,
        align: "center",
        key: "STT",
        render: (value, record, index) =>
          (currentPage - 1) * pageSize + index + 1,
        width: 50,
        fixed: "left",
      },
      {
        title: <span className={`table-header pl-4`}>Name</span>,
        dataIndex: "full_name",
        width: 150,
        fixed: "left",
        align: "left",
        render: (text, record) => (
          <span className="pl-4">{record.full_name}</span>
        ),
      },
      {
        title: <span className={`table-header pl-4`}>Code</span>,
        dataIndex: "code",
        fixed: "left",
        align: "left",
        render: (text, record) => <span className="pl-4">{record.code}</span>,
      },
      {
        title: <span className={`table-header`}>DOB</span>,
        dataIndex: "birthday",
        align: "center",
        render: (value) => <span>{moment(value).format(DATE_FORMAT)}</span>,
        fixed: "left",
      },
      {
        title: <span className={`table-header`}>SUMMARY</span>,
        children: [
          {
            title: (
              <span className={`table-header`}>
                TB{" "}
                {semester.key !== "whole_year"
                  ? `HK ${semester.shortValue}`
                  : semester.value}
              </span>
            ),
            dataIndex: ["study_summary_info", "average_semester"],
            key: "study_summary_info_average_semester",
            align: "center",
          },
          {
            title: <span className={`table-header`}>Rank</span>,
            key: "study_summary_info_ranked_academic",
            align: "center",
            render: (value, record) => {
              return (
                <SelectOption
                  ...
                />
              );
            },
          },
          {
            title: <span className={`table-header`}>Conduct</span>,
            key: "study_summary_info_conduct",
            align: "center",
            render: (value, record) => {
              return (
                <SelectOption
                  ...
                />
              );
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: <span className={`table-header`}>Day off</span>,
        dataIndex: ["study_summary_info", "day_off"],
        key: "study_summary_info_day_off",
        align: "center",
      },
      {
        title: <span className={`table-header`}>Title</span>,
        key: "study_summary_info_title",
        align: "center",
        render: (value, record) => {
          return (
            <SelectOption
              ...
            />
          );
        },
      },
      {
        title: <span className={`table-header`}>Result</span>,
        key: "study_summary_info_result",
        align: "center",
        render: (value, record) => {
          return (
            <SelectOption
              ...
            />
          );
        },
      },
    ];
  };
```

`setupColumns()`

```
const setupColumns = () => {
    filterClassHasSubject({ class_id: classId, page: 1, size: 999 })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.code === "success") {
          const data = res.data.data;

          let children = data.map((val) => {
            return {
              title: (
                <span className={`table-header`}>{val.subject_info?.name}</span>
              ),
              key: (value, record, index) => `subject_${index}`,
              width: 150,
              align: "center",
              ellipsis: true,
              render: (value, record) => {
                const point = record.average_transcript_info.find(
                  (x) =>
                    x.subject_id === val.subject_id &&
                    x.semester === semester.key
                );

                return (
                  <span>{point?.value_number}</span>
                );
              },
            };
          });

          let scoreGroup = {
            title: <span className={`table-header`}>DTB</span>,
            children,
          };

          let temp = getDefaultColumns();
          temp.splice(4, 0, scoreGroup);
          setColumns([...temp]);
        }
      });
  };
```

`Table`

```
<Table
  dataSource={summaryData}
  columns={columns}
  bordered
  rowClassName={(record, index) =>
    index % 2 === 1
      ? "odd-row attendance-row"
      : "bg-white attendance-row"
  }
  pagination={false}
  scroll={{ x: "100vw", y: 580 }}
/>
```

This is not happen when I remove the scroll Y on the `Table`.
The columns is render dynamically when `semester` or `classId` is changed.

[Before change semester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BtTq.png)

[After change semester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3a75.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was because of the property `key` in the column. The solution was to use `string` instead of using the function to return `string`.